# Perl program for parsing a Ruby file

Tags: perl

Hai anyone please provide me a code or say the perl module for parsing a ruby file.
Like it has to count the number of lines having comments. Number of lines having source code.
Extract the source code and extract the comment lines.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you actually have to parse the ruby, or is separating source and comments all you need to do?

Comment: yes. I have to write a perl script which has to find the number of lines having comment in the Ruby file and well as have to count the source code. And give the source code lines and comment lines separately. Like maintaining them separately in an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply process the ruby source file and count any line that starts with `\s*#` or is only whitespace as a comment and all else as code...

Comment: Comments can appear on a line with source code as well. Multi-line comments should also be taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a grammar for [Regexp::Grammars](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3a%3aGrammars), which will in turn parse the file for you. The module is very well documented.

I hope the following script will help you understand the idea behind parsing:

### Parser

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Regexp::Grammars;

my $parser = qr{
    <File>

    <rule: File>
        (
              (?:
                    \n
                  | <[Comment]>
              )
            | <[Comment]>
            | <[Source]>
        )+

        <rule: Comment>
              \# <InlineComment>
            | ^=begin
             <MultilineComment> \n
             ^=end

            <rule: InlineComment>
                [^\n]+

            <rule: MultilineComment>
                .*

    <rule: Source>
        [^\n]+
}xms;

my $text = do { local $/; <DATA> };

if ( $text =~ $parser ) {
    my @source;
    my @comments;

    if ( exists $/{'File'}->{'Source'} ) {
        @source = @{ $/{'File'}->{'Source'} };
    }
    if ( exists $/{'File'}->{'Comment'} ) {
        @comments = @{ $/{'File'}->{'Comment'} };
    }

    my $line = 1;
    print '__SOURCE__ [', scalar @source, "]\n";

    for (@source) {
        print "$line: $_\n";
        $line++;
    }

    print "\n\n";

    $line = 1;
    print '__COMMENTS__ [', scalar @comments, "]\n";

    for my $comment (@comments) {
        print "$line: ";

        if ( exists $comment->{'InlineComment'} ) {
            print $comment->{'InlineComment'};
        }
        elsif ( exists $comment->{'MultilineComment'} ) {
            print $comment->{'MultilineComment'};
        }

        print "\n";
        $line++;
    }
}
else {
}

__DATA__
=begin
The following code snippet was copied from:
http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/4/
=end
# Say hi to everybody
def say_hi
  if @names.nil?
    puts "..."
  elsif @names.respond_to?("each")
    # @names is a list of some kind, iterate!
    @names.each do |name|
      puts "Hello #{name}!"
    end
  else
    puts "Hello #{@names}!"
  end
end
```

### Output

```
__SOURCE__ [11]
1: def say_hi
2: if @names.nil?
3: puts "..."
4: elsif @names.respond_to?("each")
5: @names.each do |name|
6: puts "Hello #{name}!"
7: end
8: else
9: puts "Hello #{@names}!"
10: end
11: end


__COMMENTS__ [3]
1: The following code snippet was copied from:
http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/4/
2: Say hi to everybody
3: @names is a list of some kind, iterate!
```